# Best way to list all tokens of user in Solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, erc-721, openzeppelin

I am using openzeppelin erc721 library to create an NFT and need to list all the tokens of a user. The most obvious way is to iterate through all the tokens in the contract and check if the owner of the token is same as the address I have sent.

```
function tokensOfOwner(address _owner) external view returns(uint256[] ownerTokens) {
    uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);

    if (tokenCount == 0) {
        // Return an empty array
        return new uint256[](0);
    } else {
        uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](tokenCount);
        uint256 totalCats = totalSupply();
        uint256 resultIndex = 0;

        // We count on the fact that all cats have IDs starting at 1 and increasing
        // sequentially up to the totalCat count.
        uint256 catId;

        for (catId = 1; catId <= totalCats; catId++) {
            if (kittyIndexToOwner[catId] == _owner) {
                result[resultIndex] = catId;
                resultIndex++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

[Link to this solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54959/list-erc721-tokens-owned-by-a-user-on-a-web-page/66392)

Another solution that I am thinking of implementing is to have a mapping where I map the user address to an array or another mapping which includes all the tokens the user owns. Upon transferring the token to another address, I would need to remove the token from seller list and add it to buyers list. This solution sounds more reasonable but I dont know how cost efficient it will be. What are the disadvantages of this method?

Comment: Whatever you do, try to stay away from loops. They are consuming gas. Try to solve these kind of problems off-chain if you can.

Comment: take look at this https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#ERC721Enumerable and see how they implement this method _tokensOfOwner(owner)

return all tokens of owner in ERC721 is not a good idea, it is a "NFT" and such a thing you trying to do will only work for a very low number of tokens

Comment: @MajdTL then can you elaborate how properly to list all the NFT, like for marketplace but without the need of centralisation server like opensea? because it is ridiculous when u can't display the list items.

Comment: @MiratCanBayrak external view won't use gas, so actually when it's view function, always use loops if possible.

Comment: If you just want the data offChain to view it and it is not needed to be used by other smart contract then take a look at the Graph. it is a decentralized protocol for indexing and querying data from blockchains. @DellWatson

Comment: Checkout this, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70975/erc721-how-does-tokenofownerbyindex-list-tokens-owned-by-a-user this method is better than iterating over all the tokens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by the following:

Declare storage variables at the contract level

```
mapping(address => uint256[]) public userOwnedTokens;
mapping(uint256 => int256) public tokenIsAtIndex;

mint(tokenId) {
    // Prior minting logic from OpenZeppelin
    userOwnedTokens[msg.sender].push(tokenId);
    uint256 arrayLength = userOwnedTokens[msg.sender].length;
    tokenIsAtIndex[tokenId] = arrayLength;
}
```

To get all user tokens without loop, all you have to do is, this is possible as the access specifier for userOwnedTokens is public

```
contractInstance.methods.userOwnedTokens.call(address) // THIS WILL RETURN AN ARRAY OF TOKEN IDs
```

In case of transfer of tokens, change tokenIsAtIndex[tokenId] to -1

```
transfer(from, to, tokenId) {
    // Transfer logic
    uint256 tokenIndex = tokenIsAtIndex[tokenId];
    userOwnedTokens[from][tokenIndex] = 000; // TO DENOTE THAT THE TOKEN HAS BEEN TRANSFERRED, YOU CAN USE ANY OTHER NUMBER
 }
```

Next time when `userOwnedTokens` is called you can keep a check wherever the tokenId is 000, those tokens have already been transferred and you can decide not to show it to the user on the frontend.

I hope it helps!!!!!

Comment: Dont really get what is tokenIsAtIndex used for when you just call 
methods.userOwnedTokens.call(address)   tokenIsAtIndex dont have anything with that part?

Comment: I don't know why this answer get accepted, definitely wrong when I tried it.
userOwnedTokens is on array which userOwnedTokens require index so it will be `userOwnedTokens(address, uint256)` 
which make `contractInstance.methods.userOwnedTokens.call(address)` -> INVALID, from logic itself is already wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In the first answer, as you declare "mapping(address => uint256[]) public userOwnedTokens", it expects an address and an uint (position in the array) in the call function. That was my experience.

Based on suggestion made by @dwardu/@hack3r_0m, extend ERC721Enumerable, the following code worked for me, without worries with mappings and indexes:

```
function getTokenIds(address _owner) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
        uint[] memory _tokensOfOwner = new uint[](ERC721.balanceOf(_owner));
        uint i;

        for (i=0;i<ERC721.balanceOf(_owner);i++){
            _tokensOfOwner[i] = ERC721Enumerable.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return (_tokensOfOwner);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you’re already extending OpenZeppelin’s `ERC721` contract, simply extend [`ERC721Enumerable`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.1.0/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol) too, and you may then enumerate `user`’s tokens by calling `tokenOfOwnerByIndex(user, index)` for `index = 0, 1, 2, …, balanceOf(user) - 1`.