# How to know if a contact implements ERC721Enumerable

Tags: web3js, erc-721

I'm trying to list all ERC721 tokens that an address has.
For this, if the contract implements ERC721Enumerable is quite easy, I get the balance and use tokenOfOwnerByIndex.

If not, I have to do the "check all incoming transfers" method listed [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54959/list-erc721-tokens-owned-by-a-user-on-a-web-page/66392).

**My question is if there's a way to know if the contract implements ERC721Enumerable using web3.**

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ERC721Enumerable inherits ERC721 and ERC721 inherits ERC165. So this below article may help you.

https://medium.com/@chiqing/ethereum-standard-erc165-explained-63b54ca0d273

Let me know if this works for you. If not then will look for some other solution.

Comment: Fantastic, worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: @mdlapla  so I wonder what's your answer to your question?

Comment: the answer is in the medium article. If you read the article you will get the idea. BTW this article isn't mine

Comment: @JerryAn basically you have to define the interface and add it to the supportsInterface method. As Deepak correctly answered, the medium post was the solution.